# Replace value of #define directive in C

Tags: c

I want to replace directive

```
#define MAX_LINE 15
```

with variable value.

For example of behavior, if something ( text ) contains 15 or more lines #define MAX_LINE to return 15
else if the text contains less than 15 lines #define MAX_LINE to return numbers of lines.

```
for( i = 0; i < MAX_LINE; i++ ) {
   /* print lines in expandable menu window */
}
```

is this possible?

Comment: What is the something? Are you counting lines in a string?

Comment: This sounds like of one of the first basic tasks when you learn a programming language. Do you know how to declare variables in C, initialize them and assign values to them?

Comment: You definitely need a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#define`s simply replace some text with some other text. You could, for example, use this:

```
#define MAX_LINES ((num_lines > 15) ? 15 : num_lines)
```

Then you can use `MAX_LINES` as before in some statements. However, it won't work in all situations. You may have had code that looked like this:

```
const char *lines[MAX_LINES];
```

With the old `#define`, `MAX_LINES` was 15, so it expanded to this:

```
const char *lines[15];
```

That should be valid in any standards-compliant compiler. However, say you used our new `#define`. Expanded, it would look like this:

```
const char *lines[((num_lines > 15) ? 15 : num_lines)];
```

Supposing that was a global declaration, that would be invalid. Even if it was just a local declaration, it would only be valid if the compiler supports variable-length arrays.

If I were you, I'd simply try to get whatever you're trying to do to work without `#define`ing `MAX_LINES` to a non-constant expression; it's clearer that way and it will be more obvious where it would be invalid to use `MAX_LINES`.

Answer (score 3):

Then replace it

```
int MAX_LINE = 15;
```

or

```
int max_line = 15;
#define MAX_LINE max_line
```

Just keep in mind that `MAX_LINE` will no longer be a constant, i.e. you will not be able to use it anywhere a constant is required.

Basically, once it became a variable value, it no longer has anything to do with the preprocessor. It is just an ordinary variable now. Make it a variable, name it appropriately and forget about `#define`.

Comment: I *think* (it's hard to tell) what user1840007 is after is making `MAX_LINE` something like `max(15, number_of_lines)` (where `number_of_lines` is the number of lines in the text (and it's not clear if he already has this number, or if he needs to read the text and count it)).